# Assign values to data points in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to create a binary map on a plt.plot.
I have created a plot with a data point at every x,y coordinate but can't work out how to assign a binary value to each data point from a dataframe of indentical size/shape.

any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#gd is a dataframe with binary values assigned for each i,j index
gd = pd.read_csv('SIG_Warehouse.csv',header=None)

x =[]
y =[]

for i in range(gd.shape[0]):
  for j in range(gd.shape[1]):
    x.append(i)
    y.append(j)


plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

`pyplot.scatter` takes a `c=` argument for colour, and an `s=` argument for size, amongst others. Example below.

[image]

Imports and data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#
#Create some test data
#
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
X, Y = make_moons(n_samples=2500)
Y = Y[np.argsort(np.linalg.norm(X - 0.3, axis=1))]
gd = Y.reshape(50, 50)

#This is a more efficient alternative to your loop-based approach
x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(range(gd.shape[0]), range(gd.shape[1]))
x = x_grid.flatten()
y = y_grid.flatten()
```

Coloured scatter plot using (binary) data in `gd`:

```
#Since "gd" is a 2D matrix, need to flatten it to match the flattened
# x and y
gd_flat = gd.flatten()

#Colour by gd ("c=") and encode size by gd ("s=")
plt.scatter(
    x, y,
    c=gd_flat,
    s=gd_flat * 5,
    marker='s',
    edgecolor='none',
    cmap='hsv',
    label='data'
)
```

Optional plot formatting:

```
plt.gcf().legend()
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(6, 3)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.gca().spines['bottom'].set_bounds(0, 50)
plt.gca().spines['left'].set_bounds(0, 50)
plt.gca().spines['right'].set_visible(False)
plt.gca().spines['top'].set_visible(False)
plt.tight_layout()
```